# Orange3 and Python Data Export/Import

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-lab, orange

Orange 3 seems to be a great tool. However, I had trouble saving and reading my files in my python code (jupyterlab with pandas). There is a way to save the file in an `orange pickle` format but had no luck in finding a way to properly open the file.

If there is a better way in exporting data tables as well, that will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily open a pickle file that holds the data table with:

````py
from Orange.data import Table

table = Table("pickled_file.pkl")
```python
You can save the Orange Table in various formats (.tab, .csv, .pickle, ...). Just use the `save` method on the table.
 Here is the example on the Iris dataset.
````

from Orange.data import Table
table = Table("iris")
table.save("iris.csv")